# Validation on Masked Input Plugin

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I am using [Masked input plugin](https://github.com/bseth99/sandbox/blob/master/projects/jquery-ui/5-jquery-masks.html) to validate the following time format:

```
$("#time").inputmask( 'h:s' );
```

How can I disallow any time greater than '12:00'?

Answer (score 0):

You can split string and add if statement to the first item of array. Like this.

```
var str = $("#time").val(), parts;
parts = str.split(':');
if(parseInt(parts[0])>12){
  console.log('greater than 12');
}
```